# Importing multiple categories on single products

Tags: magento, menu, submenu, magmi, data-formats

My problem is getting the correct menu structure when importing my data.

I use Magento 1.9.2.2

I recieve my data in CSV format like this:

```
"sku","Cat1","Cat2","Cat3","Cat4"
"001","Plumbing","Pressfittings & pipes","Unipipe - MLC","Clutch"
"002","Tools","Handtools|Pipetools","Pipetools|Pipecutters & Scissors","Plastic scissors"
"003","Tools|Plumbing","Handtools|Pipetools|Pipes & Fittings","Pipetools|Calibration|Alupex fittings & tubes","Calibration tools|Tools  for alupex"
```

I have made a small program to strip away the "|" and what comes after, so that:

```
"002","Tools","Handtools|Pipetools","Pipetools|Pipecutters & Scissors","Plastic scissors"
```

becomes:

```
"002","Tools","Handtools","Pipetools","Plastic scissors"
```

But I would love to create all the underlaying categories, so I also get this for sku 002:

```
"002","Tools","Pipetools","Pipecutters & Scissors","Plastic scissors"
```

I believe that the structure is used by Magento somehow, but I have a hard time figuring out how to import it.

I have tried normal import for Magento after creating the categories manually, and this did not work.
I have also tried creating them with Magmi, but I cannot get Magmi to work with the multiple main and subcategories either.

Has anyone seen this data format and have a clue in the right direction, on how to get it imported to a menu structure?

I have 2500 main and subcategories all together, so manually creating them simply wont work.

Ideas, questions or comments are welcome! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MAGMI 'on-the-fly category importer' will certainly do this for you. I recommend you read the instructions on the MAGMI wiki very very carefully: all the information you need is there but I frequently find I have to double-check and re-read the details and examples on the MAGMI wiki.

MAGMI instructions for download install and running  : http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Download_and_Install_Magmi

MAGMI instructions for on-the-fly category importer : http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer

If you haven't used MAGMI before then work with a simple CSV to start with to ensure your install is set up correctly and you are able to import a csv that creates a simple product.

I think the main challenge you face is converting the CSV file format described in your question into a CSV format that MAGMI can work with. Alternatively you can write code in MAGMI to convert the CSV data but I think that might be overly complicated if this is a one-off process.

I'm not sure that I follow the syntax of your CSV example but if the first string is always a top category and then the pipe symbol means 'subcategory follows' then for

`"003","Tools|Plumbing","Handtools|Pipetools|Pipes & Fittings","Pipetools|Calibration|Alupex fittings & tubes","Calibration tools|Tools  for alupex"`

you seek to make a MAGMI CSV like this

`"sku","categories"
"003","Tools::1::1::1/Plumbing::1::0::1;;Handtools::1::1::1/Pipetools::1::0::1/Pipes & Fittings::1::0::1;;Pipetools::1::1::1/Calibration::1::0::1/Alupex fittings & tubes::1::0::1;;Calibration tools::1::1::1/Tools  for alupex::1::0::1"`

The obscure `::1::1::1` indicates `is_active`, `is_anchor` and `include_in_menu` respectively and can be omitted.

It's none of my business but I am deeply concerned by the two spaces in the subcategory label `'Tools  for alupex'` (don't start me on the lower-case Alupex or AluPEX)

Comment: Thanks Malachy, this was the solution that helped me. My categories was a bit messed up, so after some re-arranging and reading up on the links you provided, Magmi did the trick just perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create those categories programatically, not possible by import (maybe via magmi but I don't know). Place a script into your magento root and run it. This is how you could proceed (needs polishing):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');

$f = fopen($file, "r");

$row = 0;
while ( ($data = fgetcsv( $f, 0, ",") ) !== FALSE) {
    $multiple_categories = explode("|", $data);
    //save main ones
    $category->setName($multiple_categories[0])
      ->setIsActive(1)                       
      ->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS')
      ->setIsAnchor(1)
      ->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId()); //or the id of your attribute set, this is important.
    $category->save();
    unset($category);
    //now deal with children
    if(count($multiple_categories) > 1){
        i = 1;
        foreach($multiple_categories as $subcategory){
            $category->setName($multiple_categories[i])
              ->setIsActive(1)                       
              ->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS')
              ->setIsAnchor(1)
              ->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId());
            //manage parents now
            $_category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                ->addFieldToFilter('name', $multiple_categories[i-1])
                ->getFirstItem(); //this needs more work
            $parentId = $_category->getId();
            $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
            $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
            $category->save();
            unset($category);
            i++;
        }   
  }
    $row++;
}
```